# Features for a Project Management SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm looking for resources to exemplify a good layout for a project management oriented site. I've made a Project site, but that's as far as I've gotten. Has anyone run across any good resources for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you asked this same question in the general SO, but for consistency:

If you've started with a Project Site, your Task List and Calendar are going to do quite a bit for you. There's a few options you'll want to turn on, such as the Timeline in the Task List. Dig around your available Apps and experiment with what you see. You'll likely need a List for something, so check out custom lists while you're experimenting (they operate a bit like an Excel spreadsheet).

Since you're new to SharePoint, you might consider looking for O'Reilly's Information Architecture for the World Wide Web. If you'll be doing much more site design, that book will help you determine what sites need and how they should be organized. It's a fantastic book and not difficult to read, although the second half of the book is pretty specific to coded web design, which isn't what SharePoint is for new users.